# How to check if a printer is installed?

Tags: printing, hp

I use hp-setup

```
hp-setup -i -a 192.168.X.XXX
```

To install my printer. How do I check if this printer is already installed to not install it twice?

I should check it by command line with a Boolean variable.

Comment: `lpstat -t` will do it.

Comment: Can I check by its IP, if so, how?

Comment: please edit your your question with the output of `lpstat -t`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My script is

```
if [[ $(lpstat -t) = *192.168.X.XXX* ]]
then
    echo "Printer Already installed"
else
    hp-setup -i -a 192.168.X.XXX  
fi
```